# Drag/Drop between 3 ScrollViews [ iOS ]

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, draggable

Is it possible to have 3 scroll views lets say the middle is the main where is user find objects inside, then user can drag any item and drop it to the right scroll view or left scroll view so that's object will be removed from the middle and dropped either right or left depends on the uses and suppose the user dropped it to the left thus system should add new object to the left scroll view but when the user remove this object and return back to the main (middle) preferred to dropped and added in the same old index if the object was number 2 then the object will added and dropped at index 2 ..etc.

Could you help on this to make this functionality ?

Comment: yes, this can be solved.wait for a moment, i put my idea in my answer.

Comment: @ezatu丶Awaiting your kind support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the items `model1` ... `model3`;

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *mainArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *leftArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *rightArray;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *mainView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *leftView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *rightView;
```

You need make a model class such as `ItemModel` inherit `UIView` or `NSObject`, in `ItemModel.h` make some property（what property you need and a property about which `UIScrollView` contains this model）

First, put all models in the mainView's datasource`mainArray`, display models in your `self.view` and call `self.view bringSubviewToFront:` and give all models a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and a method to respond to `UIPanGestureRecognizer` so you can drag them.

**This is the most important part：**

Because you want all models to be contained by three UIViews, you must calculate the models frame between `self.view.frame` and the three `UIView` frames relationship. In fact, all modelViews is contained by `self.view`, but when visually displayed, all modelViews is contained within UIScrollViews.

Second, you already have the frame of three `UIView`, when you drag model, you can get `CGPoint` about the location of the drag, then call the method `CGRectContainsPoint(CGRect rect, CGPoint point)`, so you can get any view that contains the point you drag.

For exexample, you drag `model1` from `mainView` to `leftView`, you can get a `YES` from `CGRectContainsPoint(leftview.frame, point)`, then remove the `model1` from `mainArray` and put `model1` in `leftArray`, meanwhile you need to re-layout the three `UIViews`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

here is my share URL for the gif:https://pan.baidu.com/s/1slFBva9

Comment: i suggest you make a model class inherit `UIView`, because you need the model agree to display and drag.

Comment: Appreciate. but this was my idea and the problem is when the object is addSubview in the middle scrollview can't drag outside of middle scrollview so what could we do for that?

Comment: sorry, i forget this problem, i will change my answer, you can see how i solved this problem.

Comment: why? i test my thinking by Xcode and Objective-C, and it worked.

Comment: Share your sample to clarify please

Comment: lets me try more and reply back soon

Comment: bro could you share gif to help my brain to understand

Comment: the gif file is too large not to able to upload ,send you a website where i upload the gif .https://pan.baidu.com/s/1eSMd23w  see if you can open it ?

Comment: Perfect, I think this is what am looking for and I will continue on this functionality, other important thing what if I want to return the object back to its original point if the dropped done in mistake area or empty area?

Comment: i found this problem too , and now i resloved it already. notice my new upload image and code changed.

Comment: I believe this functionality has limitation, in order to get the benefit from UIScrollView [scrolling vertically] and add x times of models inside UIScrollView we need to avoid adding model as subview of self.view, what do you think ?

Comment: this is only a demo for what effort you want, if you want to use it for your iOS app, you have to improve code to suit your real logic. if you have another problem on your code ,pl let me know , i will do my best to help you .

Comment: thank you for your support I will see how to handle this